# Why is a C++ Std lib container created non-empty in a linked lib?

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries

I'm trying to link a library (Poco Project - JSON) to my project, which itself outputs a Dynamic library (dll).

When I create an instance of a class defined in this lib (a JSON "Object"), its default constructor creates both a std::map and a std::deque, which sometimes are created non-empty (I have observed either one with this behavior). This then naturally results in undefined behavior later.

This only happens when my project is in release mode (debug symbols on). To make sure this is not because of some release-mode debugger problems I printed out the size of the container - same result.

The libraries I want to use are Poco "Foundation" and "JSON", I compiled both of them myself in the same IDE (I have to use VS 2008), I have assured that the runtime-library setting is equal in all three pojects (multi-threaded DLL /md)

I have tried both static and dynamic linking - same result. 
So, how can this be, and what other settings have I missed to check?

Comment: @Elemental, right, changed the title. As written, I tried both static and dynamic for the Poco libs, the actual project's output is a dll. 
And 2nd: Could this really account for bad std container constructions? How can I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, I think I figured it out myself: Among some other odd preprocessor defines in the project, somewhere 
`_SECURE_SCL=0` was set.

Removing this define resulted in the expected behavior of the Poco library usage (constructor created empty object), but instead the 'main' application crashed. I therefore copied the preprocessor defines of the main project to the poco projects and rebuilt them (Foundation and JSON). Seems to work now.

Comment: _SECURE_SCL was defined in a Poco project?

Comment: @Alex No, _SECURE_SCL was defined in the project I wanted to use Poco in. As I have found out in the meantime, Visual Studio 2008 had  _SECURE_SCL activated per default even in release mode. Since this led to quite some performance reductions (e.g. with hash_map) many developers back then decided to switch it off explicitely. However, apparently all code and libs used MUST then deactivate it also. See http://preshing.com/20110807/the-cost-of-_secure_scl/ for this.